# Creating an AuthService to check if user is logged in

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have an AngularJS app which communicates with a Laravel PHP backend. Sending a GET request to `/api/checkLogin` will return `{ logged: false, username: undefined, id: undefined }` if the user is not logged in, otherwise, it will return something like `{ logged: true, username: 'John', id: 123 }`.

I am not too familiar with using AngularJS services, but I would like to set up a service called `AuthService` that can, well, perform my app's authentication services.

I would like to implement the following functions: `AuthService.loggedIn`, `AuthService.isAdmin`, `AuthService.username`, and `AuthService.id`.

I want these functions implemented in such a way that calling one will set the values for all the rest. For example, let's say I call `AuthService.isAdmin`. This function will check if `isAdmin` is set, if so, it will return the value of `isAdmin`. If `isAdmin` is not set, it will make an HTTP request to `/api/checkLogin`, set the values for `loggedIn`, `isAdmin`, `username`, and `id`, and then return the value of `isAdmin`. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the service I have tried putting together:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var loggedIn;
    var isAdmin;
    var username;
    var id;

    var checkLogin = function() {
        if(loggedIn != undefined) {
            return loggedIn
        } else {
            setUserData(checkLogin);
        }
    }
    var checkAdmin = function() {
        if(isAdmin != undefined) {
            return isAdmin
        } else {
            setUserData(checkLogin);
        }
    }
    var returnUsername = function() {
        if(username != undefined) {
            return username
        } else {
            setUserData(checkLogin);
        }
    }
    var returnId = function() {
        if(id != undefined) {
            return id
        } else {
            setUserData(checkLogin);
        }
    }


    // Our function call which will set our loggedIn, isAdmin, username, and id values
    var setUserData = function(callback) {
        $http.get(baseURL+'/api/checkLogin').success(function(data) {
            loggedIn = data.logged;
            if(loggedIn) {
                isAdmin = data.is_admin;
                username = data.username;
                id = data.id;
            }
            callback();
        });
    }


    return {
        loggedIn: function() { return checkLogin(); },
        isAdmin: function() { return checkAdmin(); },
        username: function() { return returnUsername(); },
        id: function() { return returnId(); },
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you want to use `checkLogin` as a callback, but instead of doing it the way you have it, return the promise back to `checkLogin` from `setUserData`.  Then in `checkLogin`, create your own deferred to handle the results.

You are acting on asynchronous logic by introducing the `$http` call, so `checkLogin` is going to need to return a promise in all cases:

```
var checkLogin = function() {

        // Create a custom deferred
        var defer = $q.defer();

        if(loggedIn != undefined) {
            // Resolve your deferred with the value of logged in
            defer.resolve(loggedIn);
        } else {
            setUserData().then(function (data) {
               console.log('Set user data returned successfully');
               loggedIn = data.logged;
               if(loggedIn) {
                  isAdmin = data.is_admin;
                  username = data.username;
                  id = data.id;
                  defer.resolve(loggedIn);
               } else {
                  defer.reject();
               }
            }, function () {
               console.log('setUserData failed');
               defer.reject();
            });
        }

        return defer.promise;
    }

var setUserData = function() {
        return $http.get(baseURL+'/api/checkLogin');
    }
```

`AuthService.loggedIn()` will now return a promise.  You have to resolve the promise to get the value out of it:

```
AuthService.loggedIn().then(function (data) { 
     console.log(data);
});
```

The function passed to then above will be called when the promise is resolved with the value that the promise was resolved with.  In this case, its the value of `data.logged` because thats what was passed to `defer.resolve` in your `checkLogin` function.

Here's some reading on Promises:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I've updated my code, now `AuthService.loggedIn()` is only returning `undefined`, even though it should return only `true` or `false`. How can I catch any errors with the `$http.get` call and return that (if there is an error)? A call to `api/checkLogin` will always return a value of true or false for logged), unless there was some error in the request.

Comment: In Javascript, if you don't specify a return, the function will return undefined.  In your checkLogin method, there is no return in the else block.  That's why you see undefined.  To catch an error in the $http call, simply add an error callback:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Ok, I understand. How can I ensure the `checkLogin` function waits for `setUserData` to finish, then return whatever value `setUserData` sets `loggedIn` to?

Comment: Thanks! I just spent some time trying to understand promises. If you know of some good resource that will explain them to me, please share the link. When using your code, "Set user data returned successfully" is written to the console, but the value of `console.log(AuthService.loggedIn());` (called inside my controller) is `d {$$state: Object, then: function, catch: function, finally: function}`. Why is this? I'm expecting it to return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

loginService this

```
var app=angular.module('myApp');
app.factory('loginService', function ($http, $location) {
  return {
    login: function (data, scope) {
      var $promise = $http.post('api.php/site/login', data);
      $promise.then(function (msg) {
        var uId = msg.data.key;
       if (msg.data.key) {

          $location.path('/abAdmin/home');
        } else {
          $location.path('/abAdmin');
        }
      });
    },
    logout: function () {
      $http.post('api.php/site/logout');
      $location.path('/abAdmin');
    },
    isLogged: function () {
      var $check = $http.post('api.php/site/checkSession');
      return $check;
    }
  }
});
```

and your app.js

```
var app=angular.module('myApp');

app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, loginService) {
  var routPermission = [
              '/abAdmin/home',
              '/abAdmin/category',
              '/abAdmin/category/:id'];


  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (e, current) {

     if ( routPermission.indexOf(current.$$route.originalPath) != -1) {
        var connected = loginService.isLogged();
        connected.then(function (data) {
          if (!data.data.isLogged) {
            logged=true;
            $location.path('abAdmin');
          }
        })
    }
  });
});
```